# How to make formula in text format to execute in another cell without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to evaluate a sum of values stored as text from a defined cell to another cell without using VBA in excel.

Say

```
Input:
 A1 = "7+1+2" (stored as text) 
Output:
 A2 = 10 (result of the sum from A1 stored as number)
```

I couldn't find any way to do it without VBA (the file has to be shared and couldn't share it as .xlsm).

Thnx

Comment: This has definitely been asked before. Can you give more samples? For example, would it always be integers seperated by a plus sign?

Comment: The format is always a sum like "X+Y+Z+....+n" as text and i cannot do manipulation. just add a column with formula to dinamiccaly evaluate. Could be float.

Comment: Right, I've found duplicates and just linked the 1st. Note that `TEXTSPLIT()` is taking over for newer versions of Excel as per the answer below.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, shall I add the `TEXTSPLIT()` option in the above link you have shared.

Comment: Just leave as is I suppose. The two posts are now crosslinked anyway

Comment: @JvdV Sir, alright sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TEXTSPLIT()`

```
=SUM(--TEXTSPLIT(A1,"+"))
```

---

Use `FILTERXML()`

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"))
```

---

Use `TRIM()`, `MID()`, `REPT()`, `SUBSTITUTE()`, with `SUMPRODUCT()`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN($A$1:$Z$1)*100-99,100))/1,0))
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanx for the alternatives! unfortunatelly textsplit isn't available to every user of the sheet. The other 2 works just great!!

Comment: @FrancescoCattaneo glad to know it worked for you